please. I keep getting openai.beta.threads.runs.stream is not a function
I tried call assistant api in nextjs and vercel deployment, but i keep getting stream not a function., this however works in local host. Has anyone experienced this. I have tried searching online but not solution.
return AssistantResponse(
    { threadId, messageId: createdMessage.id },
    async ({ forwardStream, sendDataMessage }) => {
      // Run the assistant on the thread
      const runStream = openai.beta.threads.runs.stream(threadId, {
        assistant_id:
          process.env.ASSISTANT_ID ??
          (() => {
            throw new Error('ASSISTANT_ID is not set');
          })(),
      });
 
      // forward run status would stream message deltas
      let runResult = await forwardStream(runStream);
 

